# Is there a non-relative unit of measurement for the volume of sound?

Tags: acoustics

I understand dB to be the main unit of measurement of the volume of a sound, but (to the best of my limited knowledge), dB only gives a measurement of the volume of a sound relative to the volume of another sound. Is there such thing as a universal scale for simply measuring volume non-relatively? If not, could someone explain why there has never been a need for such a unit of measurement?

Comment: Something like [sound intensity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_intensity)?

Comment: Is there any measurement that is non-relative? We measure volume as x dB above a certain level. We measure distance as y metres from a certain point. We measure time as z seconds from a certain moment. All measurements are relative to something else because a non-relative number with units is meaningless.

Comment: @Jim: temperature, volume (capacity not loudness), mass?

Comment: @JohnRennie Temperature is relative to the zero of the scale (300 K above absolute zero). Strictly speaking, mass isn't directly measured and all of the associated measurements to find mass are relative, but mass is relative as well (42kg more than nothing). Any measurement is usually relative to the zero on the scale (except when the zero is not physically meaningful). Setting the zero to be trivial (like 0kg) does not make the measurement less relative. It only means you do not have to fully understand the relative nature of the measurement in order to utilise it.

Comment: @Jim: that's quibbling and you know it. Zero's of time and distance are relative because the measurements have a shift symmetry. For temp, volume and mass the zero's are absolute because there is no shift symmetry. There is a fundamental difference between the two.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'll admit to a bit of quibbling. But temperature is relative. It's just that when we shift the zero, we usually call the new system Celsius. :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the pressure generated by the sound wave or the energy it transmits. For example zero decibels is $10^{-12}$ W/m$^2$.

I suspect the dB scale originated because the preception of volume in human hearing is logarithmic i.e. we perceive each successive doubling as a linear volume increment. The dB scale is also logarithmic and maps well onto human perception of volume. It's also very convenient for expressing signal to noise ratios as these tend to span many orders of magnitude.

Comment: Note that sound volume is often measured in dBa which is actually a "perception-adjusted" value, since the ear does not experience all frequencies at the same intensity for equal power.